# Symfony setter injection for polymorphic service

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, soa

I'm using Symfony 5.4 and PHP 7.4 with the default service configuration. I have an abstract service like this:

```php
abstract class Parent
{
    protected FooInterface $fooDependency;
    public abstract function setFooDependency(FooInterface $fooDependency): void;
}
```

In my child classes, I want to inject different implementations of `FooInterface` for each child. The problem is that PHP rightly complains about the child method's declaration not being compatible if the argument's type is anything other than `FooInterface`:

```php
class Child extends Parent
{
    public abstract function setFooDependency(FooService $fooDependency): void {}
}
```

I can solve this by not defining `setFooDependency()` in the abstract parent, but that kind of defeats the purpose of having the abstract class in the first place (I want to enforce a contract!)

Another workaround is to implement `setFooDependency()` in the parent class (instead of making it abstract), then in `services.yaml` manually specify the argument for each child class:

```yaml
services:
    App\Service\Child:
        calls:
            - setFooDependency: [App\Service\FooService]
```

But I'm not fond of this, because anyone extending the abstract class has to magically know to go and add the service definition.

**I'm hoping I'm missing an easy solution? What I want is to:**

- Enforce child classes having a setter method (or some other way to inject the dependency)
- Allow each child class to inject a different implementation of `FooInterface`
- Use autowiring so I don't clutter my services file or confuse future devs

Comment: It is an annoying `feature`.  You could make a FooInterface [service locator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html) and inject it.  The child would then pull out the specific implementation it needs.  That keeps everyone happy for an extra line of code.  On the other hand you do need to think about why PHP does this.  You say you want a contract but you are in fact conceptually violating the contract in your child classes.

Comment: @Cerad I disagree that I'm violating the contract. I am using polymorphism. For example, `FooInterface` defines a contract that there's a `getName()` method returning a string. In my child classes, I need to call `getName()`. I don't care which implementation of `getName()` I get, as long as I know the method exists and returns a string. The only way I'm violating the contract is if one of my child classes depends on behavior not defined in the contract, in which case my IDE is going to complain about an unknown method, etc.

Comment: [Named aliases](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#dealing-with-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-type) is probably the easiest approach.  Your child class signature would be `FooInterface $fooService1` where the argument name would be mapped to a particular implementation of FooInterface.  Symfony does this quite a bit with things like the LoggerInterface so it should be future developer proof.  You could even use a compiler pass to create the alias based on the service class name.

Comment: I would still say your original approach was a violation.  The parent says that a FooInterface will be injected.  The child says no, I'll accept FooService which of course could have additional public methods.  Which could end up being a problem if one of your future developers did not realize that adding methods to a FooInterface implementation was a no no because of what a particular child class does.  I know it is off-topic but PHP appears to agree with me.

Comment: By the way, you can also use the [Target or Autowire attribute](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#dealing-with-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-type) to specify which service to inject without involving the services.yaml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want is to:
>
> - Enforce child classes having a setter method (or some other way to inject the dependency)
> - Allow each child class to inject a different implementation of FooInterface
> - Use autowiring so I don't clutter my services file or confuse future devs

There are various methods to achieve polymorphism in PHP, but it seems that you may be able to resolve this issue by defining an abstract method to retrieve the `FooInterface` instance instead of a setter method. This would enable you to inject a concrete `FooInterface` implementation directly into your constructor while maintaining immutability.

```
interface FooInterface
{
    public function getName(): string;
}

class ConcreteFoo implements FooInterface
{
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return 'a string';
    }
}

abstract class Father
{
    public function doSomething(): void
    {
        $name = $this->getFoo()->getName();
        
        // ...
    }

    abstract protected function getFoo(): FooInterface;
}

class Child extends Father
{
    private ConcreteFoo $foo;
    
    public function __construct(ConcreteFoo $foo) 
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }
    
    protected function getFoo(): ConcreteFoo
    {
        return $this->foo;
    }
}
```

By using this approach, your parent class will not depend on a property, but rather on a method that every child class must implement. This will allow for greater flexibility, maintainability, and the DI autowiring won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easier using the constructor:

```php
abstract class Parent
{
    protected FooInterface $fooDependency;

    publich function __construct(FooInterface $fooDependency) :void
    {
        $this->fooDependency = $fooDependency;
    }
}
```

Then you can define each implementation in `services.yml` without worring about calling a method:

```yaml
YourNamespace\Child:
  class: YourNamespace\Child
  arguments: [@your_foo_implementation_alias_for_this_child]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a parent class (for example FooObject) for FooInterface and FooService.

Make FooInterface and FooService ... extends from this new class

Define $fooDependency as FooObject

Comment: Then how does Symfony know the correct implementation of FooInterface to inject?

Comment: I don't know if Symfony knows it, maybe you should check in your method if it's an instance of FooService and throw an error if not. Hope it helps you.